# How Traverse nested JSON in order with root node items

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, logic

I have a nested JSON structure, like a playlist can have images, videos, this playlist can have another nested playlist too.

So I wish to get output like when I traverse top most playlist from start to end, get it nested/child playlist's item just the one which falls in topmost loop index.

Example One: input structure and it's expected output:
[image]

Example Two: input structure and it's expected output:
[image]
[image]

**so far I have tried this**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>

        $.getJSON( "https://5da7520623fa7400146975dd.mockapi.io/api/playlist", function(data){
            iterate(data.contents, 3)
        });


        //*******response is received and passed, all your logic goes here*********
        function iterate(contents, maxRound) {
            for(i = 1; i <= maxRound; i++) {
                parse(contents,i)
            }
        }

        function parse(contents, cycle) {
            $.each(contents, function(i, content) {
                if(content.type == "playlist") {
                    var contentsLength = content.contents.length
                    var indexForRound = cycle % contentsLength
                    if(contentsLength == cycle) {
                        indexForRound = contentsLength - 1
                    }else {
                        indexForRound = indexForRound - 1
                    }
                    const onlyContentToChild = content.contents[indexForRound]
                    parse([onlyContentToChild], 1)
                }else {
                    $("#contents").append('<li> '+ content.name +' </li>');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <ol id="contents">
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note: Calling of API i.e [get playlist](https://5da7520623fa7400146975dd.mockapi.io/api/playlist) returns response matching with example two

Comment: I do not really understand the problem you want to solve. Can you add more details? Like in the first example - how do you decide, how many rounds you compute? By the number of the longest playlist? It would help me to understand your problem if you could describe it a bit more detailled.

Comment: what does maxRound represent?

Comment: What would happen if there were three top level images instead of two? Would it return more than 4 files per round?

Comment: @SimonvanEndern Thanks, Yes, by the longest playlist, I'll edit my question to make it more clear

Comment: @D.Seah The maximum number of the round I need to iterate top most playlist until all items is visited, like in example one maxRound is 3 and in example two it's 9, as of now it's hardcoded and I don't know if my approach is right or how would I calculate this maxRound just I hardcoded with my reference example image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple recursive solution

```js
const myData = { contents: [{ name: 'image 1', type: 'file' }, { name: 'playlist 1', type: 'playlist', level: 1, contents: [{ name: 'image 3', type: 'file' }, { name: 'playlist 101', type: 'playlist', level: 2, contents: [{ name: 'image 101', type: 'file' }, { name: 'image 102', type: 'file' }, { name: 'image 103', type: 'file' }, { name: 'image 104', type: 'file' }] }, { name: 'image 4', type: 'file' }] }, { name: 'image 2', type: 'file' }, { name: 'playlist 2', type: 'playlist', level: 1, contents: [{ name: 'image 5', type: 'file' }, { name: 'image 6', type: 'file' }, { name: 'image 7', type: 'file' }] }] };

const Iterator = (data) => {
  const state = { idx: -1 };
  const next = (curData, curState) => {
    if (curData.type === 'file') {
      return curData.name;
    }
    if (!('contents' in curState)) {
      curState.contents = Array.from(
        { length: curData.contents.length },
        () => ({ idx: -1 })
      );
    }
    curState.idx = (curState.idx + 1) % curData.contents.length;
    return next(curData.contents[curState.idx], curState.contents[curState.idx]);
  };
  return () => Array.from(
    { length: data.contents.length },
    () => next(data, state)
  );
};

const next = Iterator(myData);
for (let idx = 0; idx < 13; idx += 1) {
  console.log(next());
}
// => [ 'image 1', 'image 3', 'image 2', 'image 5' ]
// => [ 'image 1', 'image 101', 'image 2', 'image 6' ]
// => [ 'image 1', 'image 4', 'image 2', 'image 7' ]
// => [ 'image 1', 'image 3', 'image 2', 'image 5' ]
// => [ 'image 1', 'image 102', 'image 2', 'image 6' ]
// => [ 'image 1', 'image 4', 'image 2', 'image 7' ]
// => [ 'image 1', 'image 3', 'image 2', 'image 5' ]
// => [ 'image 1', 'image 103', 'image 2', 'image 6' ]
// => [ 'image 1', 'image 4', 'image 2', 'image 7' ]
// => [ 'image 1', 'image 3', 'image 2', 'image 5' ]
// => [ 'image 1', 'image 104', 'image 2', 'image 6' ]
// => [ 'image 1', 'image 4', 'image 2', 'image 7' ]
// => [ 'image 1', 'image 3', 'image 2', 'image 5' ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Here is the updated version that dynamically terminates

```js
const myData = { contents: [{ name: 'image 1', type: 'file' }, { name: 'playlist 1', type: 'playlist', level: 1, contents: [{ name: 'image 3', type: 'file' }, { name: 'playlist 101', type: 'playlist', level: 2, contents: [{ name: 'image 101', type: 'file' }, { name: 'image 102', type: 'file' }, { name: 'image 103', type: 'file' }, { name: 'image 104', type: 'file' }] }, { name: 'image 4', type: 'file' }] }, { name: 'image 2', type: 'file' }, { name: 'playlist 2', type: 'playlist', level: 1, contents: [{ name: 'image 5', type: 'file' }, { name: 'image 6', type: 'file' }, { name: 'image 7', type: 'file' }] }] };

const iterate = (data) => {
  const state = { idx: -1 };
  const progress = { cur: 0, max: 0 };
  const next = (curData, curState) => {
    if (curData.type === 'file') {
      return curData.name;
    }
    const length = curData.contents.length;
    if (!('contents' in curState)) {
      curState.contents = Array.from({ length }, () => ({ idx: -1 }));
      progress.max += length;
    }
    if (curState.idx === length - 1) {
      progress.cur -= curState.idx;
      curState.idx = 0;
    } else {
      progress.cur += 1;
      curState.idx += 1;
    }
    return next(curData.contents[curState.idx], curState.contents[curState.idx]);
  };
  const nextBatch = () => Array.from(
    { length: data.contents.length },
    () => next(data, state)
  );

  const result = [];
  do {
    result.push(nextBatch());
  } while (progress.cur !== progress.max);
  return result;
};

console.log(iterate(myData));
/* => [
  [ 'image 1', 'image 3', 'image 2', 'image 5' ],
  [ 'image 1', 'image 101', 'image 2', 'image 6' ],
  [ 'image 1', 'image 4', 'image 2', 'image 7' ],
  [ 'image 1', 'image 3', 'image 2', 'image 5' ],
  [ 'image 1', 'image 102', 'image 2', 'image 6' ],
  [ 'image 1', 'image 4', 'image 2', 'image 7' ],
  [ 'image 1', 'image 3', 'image 2', 'image 5' ],
  [ 'image 1', 'image 103', 'image 2', 'image 6' ],
  [ 'image 1', 'image 4', 'image 2', 'image 7' ],
  [ 'image 1', 'image 3', 'image 2', 'image 5' ],
  [ 'image 1', 'image 104', 'image 2', 'image 6' ],
  [ 'image 1', 'image 4', 'image 2', 'image 7' ]
] */
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

If no `type` of `file` is present this might crash badly though.

Comment: great answer, just one thing is missing: image 104 from playlist 101 is not there in the output

Comment: I'm sure you figured it out already; I just didn't loop far enough in the output. Updated

Comment: @vincet thanks again, just one more question, how can I get max loop count dynamically, instead of it's hardcoded i.e 13 currently

Comment: updated, is this what you are looking for? Also I'm sure this can be optimized quite a bit

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach:

```js
const makeFn = (fns, i = -1) => () => 
  fns [i = (i + 1) % fns .length] ()

const makeHandler = ({type, name, contents}) => 
  type == 'playlist'
    ? makePlaylistFn (contents)
    : () => name

const makePlaylistFn = (contents) => 
  makeFn (contents .map (makeHandler)) 

const makePlaylist = ({contents}, play = makePlaylistFn (contents)) => (count) => 
  Array .from (
    {length: count}, 
    () => Array .from ({length: contents .length}, play)
  )

const data = {contents: [{name: "image 1", type: "file"}, {name: "playlist 1", type: "playlist", level: 1, contents: [{name: "image 3", type: "file"}, {name: "playlist 101", type: "playlist", level: 2, contents: [{name: "image 101", type: "file"}, {name: "image 102", type: "file"}, {name: "image 103", type: "file"}, {name: "image 104", type: "file"}]}, {name: "image 4", type: "file"}]}, {name: "image 2", type: "file"}, {name: "playlist 2", type: "playlist", level: 1, contents: [{name: "image 5", type: "file"}, {name: "image 6", type: "file"}, {name: "image 7", type: "file"}]}]}

const myPlaylist = makePlaylist (data)

console .log (myPlaylist (12))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

To see how this works, we can imagine what it would be like if we converted our data into this format:

```js
const foo = ((i) => {
  const fns = [
    () => 3,
    () => 4,
  ]
  return () => fns[i = (i + 1) % fns.length]()
})(-1)

const bar = ((i) => {
  const fns = [
    () => 5,
    () => 6,
    () => 7,
  ]
  return () => fns[i = (i + 1) % fns.length]()
})(-1)

const baz = ((i) => {
  const fns = [
    () => 1,
    foo,
    () => 2,
    bar,
  ]
  return () => fns[i = (i + 1) % fns.length]()
})(-1)

const qux = () => Array.from({length: 4}, baz)

console .log (
  Array .from ({length: 6}, qux)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Our output is just an array formed by six individual calls to `qux`.  But `qux` just makes four calls to `baz`.  Here is where it gets more interesting.  `baz` cycles through four function, returning the result of the next one on each call.  The four functions are `() => 1`, `foo`, `() => 2`, and `bar`.  `foo` and `bar` are structured the same with `foo` using the two functions `() => 3` and `() => 4` and `bar` using the three functions `() => 5`, `() => 6`, and `() => 7`.

So the code above is designed to turn your data structure into such a list of nested functions.  Central is `makePlaylistFn`, which creates our main function (equivalent to `baz` above, by mapping our values with `makeHandler`, which distinguishes between `"playlist"` and `"file"` inputs, recursively calling back to `makePlaylistFn` for the former and returning a simple function for the latter.  The resulting functions are passed to `makeFn`, which turns an array of functions into one that calls them cyclically on each invocation.

We finally wrap this up with `makePlayList`, which calls `makePlaylistFn` to generate that root function, and returns a function which takes a positive integer, returning that many arrays of `n` calls the the main function, where `n` is the length of the outermost playlist.

---

This still leaves an interesting question.  How many times do we call this function?  Your samples above seem to suggest you want to stop once you've seen every value.  I'm sure we could figure that out, although it might be tricky.

Another possibility is to run this until you've cycled through everything and are starting again. This is more tractable, using a least-common-multiple technique on the various nested playlists.  But it would need six calls for your simple case and twelve for your more complex one.  I can take a swing at that if you're interested.

### Update

You wanted to know how to cycle once through the values of your playlists.  This replacement for `makePlaylist` should do it:

```js
const gcd = (a, b) => 
  (b > a) ? gcd (b, a) : b == 0 ? a : gcd (b, a % b)
const lcm = (a, b) => 
  a / gcd (a, b) * b
const lcmAll = (ns) => 
  ns .reduce (lcm, 1)

const period = (contents) => lcmAll (
  [contents .length, ... contents .map (({type, name, contents}) => 
    type == 'playlist' ? period (contents) : 1
  )]
)

const makePlaylist = ({contents}) => {
  const f1 = makePlaylistFn (contents)
  const f2 = () => Array .from ({length: contents .length}, f1)
  return Array .from ({length: period (contents)}, f2)
}
```

We start with three mathematical function we will need to find the period of repetition.  We will need to find the least common multiple of an array of integers.  This is what `lcmAll` is for  For instance, `lcmAll([12, 15, 20, 35])` yields `420`, the least common multiple of those integers.  It is built as a simple reduction of our least common multiple function, `lcm`, which in turn is built atop a greatest common divisor, `gcd` function.

Using that, we recursively find the LCM of each of our images/playlists, in `period`.  And finally, we rewrite `makePlaylist` to use that to determine how many arrays to create.  The rest would remain the same.  You can see it in action by expanding this snippet:

```js
// utility functions
const gcd = (a, b) => 
  (b > a) ? gcd (b, a) : b == 0 ? a : gcd (b, a % b)
const lcm = (a, b) => 
  a / gcd (a, b) * b
const lcmAll = (ns) => 
  ns .reduce (lcm, 1)


// helper functions
const makeFn = (fns, i = -1) => () => 
  fns [i = (i + 1) % fns .length] ()

const makeHandler = ({type, name, contents}) => 
  type == 'playlist'
    ? makePlaylistFn (contents)
    : () => name

const period = (contents) => lcmAll (
  [contents .length, ... contents .map (({type, name, contents}) => 
    type == 'playlist' ? period (contents) : 1
  )]
)

const makePlaylistFn = (contents) => 
  makeFn (contents .map (makeHandler)) 


// main function
const makePlaylist = ({contents}) => {
  const f1 = makePlaylistFn (contents)
  const f2 = () => Array .from ({length: contents .length}, f1)
  return Array .from ({length: period (contents)}, f2)
}


// sample data
const data = {contents: [{name: "image 1", type: "file"}, {name: "playlist 1", type: "playlist", level: 1, contents: [{name: "image 3", type: "file"}, {name: "playlist 101", type: "playlist", level: 2, contents: [{name: "image 101", type: "file"}, {name: "image 102", type: "file"}, {name: "image 103", type: "file"}, {name: "image 104", type: "file"}]}, {name: "image 4", type: "file"}]}, {name: "image 2", type: "file"}, {name: "playlist 2", type: "playlist", level: 1, contents: [{name: "image 5", type: "file"}, {name: "image 6", type: "file"}, {name: "image 7", type: "file"}]}]}


// demo
console.log (makePlaylist (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: Thanks, Scott, Yes, It will be a great help to me if we can stop once cycled through everything and starting again, I am still trying to understand the things :D

Comment: @CMSSignage: Added an update to handle that.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, to be honest being a mediocre developer, it will take me around a day to go through this code and explanation to understand it properly, for now, I'll test this with a couple of more test cases and use

Comment: @CMSSignage: I'm glad you like it.  The trickiest bit, I think is the handling of the index `i` in `makeFn`.  (Hint: lookup closures, if you don't already understand them.)  If you can make sense of that function, then I think the rest should be easier.